# Elementary topology problem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

A function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *bounded at a point* $x_0$ provided that there are positive numbers $\varepsilon$ and $M$ so that $|f (x)| < M$ for all $x \in (x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)$.

1. Show that the set of points at which a function is bounded is open.
2. Let $E$ be an arbitrary closed set. Is it possible to construct a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that the set of points at which $f$ is not bounded is precisely the set $E$?

I am not sure what to do with this problem. I am having a lot of trouble understanding this part of the course so any topology-related help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you do the first part? Try to find a open neighbourhood around each point.

Comment: I also see that you have not accepted a single answer to your latest questions, making me reluctant to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part:

Let $B$ be the set of points at which $f$ is bounded, and choose an arbitrary $x_0\in B$.  You have to find a $\delta$ such that $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\subseteq B$.

Since $x\in B$, we know that there is an $M$ and a $\varepsilon>0$ such that 
$$f\big[(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\big]\subseteq [-M,M].$$

So, if you put $\delta=\varepsilon/2$, then what can you say about an arbitrary element $x\in (x_0-\delta/2,x_0+\delta/2)$?

---

For the second part:

**Important note:**  On reflection, I needed to be a bit more subtle here.  I have left my original answer below, for reference, but it is flawed.  This answer avoids the earlier error, and is more elegant to boot!

I should note that the differences are slight.  The new answer is only a modification of the original one, not a complete rewrite.  However, I thought it would be easier to present it in isolation, rather than explain how I got from one to the other.

The answer is still yes.  And we still work by constructing a suitable function.  However, we have to be careful that no points in $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ are limit points of the sequences used to approximate members of $\partial E$. This can be done, but requires a little more finesse than I used the first time.

I *dyadic* rational number is one which can be expressed in the form $m/2^{n}$, where $m$ is odd.  The dyadic rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that every real number can be expressed as a limit of a sequence of dyadic rational numbers.  In fact, we can go further, by defining, for each real $x$, a *canonical* dyadic sequence converging to $x$:

> Let $x$ be a real number.  The *canonical* dyadic sequence approximating $x$ is the sequence $\langle d_{n}\vert n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ given by $$d_{n}=\max_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{\frac{m}{2^{n}} \, \left \vert \frac{m}{2^{n}}< x\right.\right\}.$$  Let $\mathcal{D}_{x}$ denote the set of dyadic rationals in the canonical sequence associated with $x$.

We now construct our function $f$.  Let $A=\bigcup_{x\in E}\mathcal{D}_{x}$.  Then for each dyadic rational $x=(2p+1)/2^{n}\in A$, define $f(x)=n$. For all $x\notin A$, define $f(x)=0$.

All you have to do now is prove the following:

1. If $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then $f$ is unbounded at $x$.
2. If $x$ is not a limit point of $A$, then $f$ us bounded at $x$.
3. The set of limit points of $A$ is $E$.

(You might first want to prove that the canonical dyadic sequence converging to $x$ is a non-decreasing sequence that really does converge to $x$.  The fact that $E$ is closed is used when proving that $x\notin E$ is not a limit point of $A$.)

Note that instead of dyadic rationals, we could just as well have used finite decimals. You may find that more intuitive.

Note also that my term *canonical dyadic sequence* is not actually canon!  It makes sense in this context, but don't go around using it in public without defining it first.

---

**Original answer**

The answer is *yes*.  We now construct such a function.

Note that any closed set $E$ can be written 
$$ E= \partial E \cup E^{\circ}.$$

Start by defining $f(x)=0$ for all $x\notin E$.  Now we need to ensure that the function is unbounded in every neighborhood of every element of $E$. To do this, consider the rational points inside $E$.  Suppose that $q=m/n\in E^{\circ}$, with $m$ and $n$ relatively prime.  Put $f(q)=n$.  It is pretty easy to see that for $x\in\ E^{\circ}$ (or indeed for any $x\in\overline{E^{\circ}}$), $f$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $x$. You can just leave $f(x)=0$ when $x\in E$ is irrational.

But what about the isolated points of $E$?  To ensure that $f$ is unbounded in the neighborhoods of these points, we need to overwrite some of the values we defined earlier.

For points  $x\in\partial E$ (the boundary of $E$): there is necessarily a sequence in $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ (the complement of $E$) which converges to $E$.

Let $\langle x_{n}\vert n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ be one such sequence.  We just need to ensure that $\limsup f(x_{n})=\infty$.  The easiest way to do this is simply to define $f(x_{n})=n$, but this could potentially cause problems if we have overlapping sequences.  The easiest way I can think of to get around this problem is to use the same trick with rationals that we used before. Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we can assume without loss of generality that all the $x_{n}$ are rationals.  If $x_{n}=a_{n}/b_{n}$, with $a_n$ and $b_n$ being relatively prime, we can avoid any ambiguities concerning the value of $f$ by simply setting $f(x_n)=b_n$.

It is immediate from its construction that $f$ is unbounded at every point in $E$. I'll leave you to prove that $E$ is bounded at every $x\notin E$.  It is at this point in the argument that you will have to use the fact that $E$ is closed.